# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use the sift function in open cv, when I do:

```
cv2.xfeatures2d
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'
```

even `cv2.SIFT()` does not work. However this seems to work:

```
cv2.orb_create()
```

I am on open cv 3.3.0, using opencv-contrib-python. I tried using opencv-python but that also gave me same errors.

I tried uninstalling and reinstsalling as well using pip. I am on osx.

Comment: The `opencv-python` is main module, while `opencv-contrib-python` is addition module(contains `nonfree` such as SIFT`). You should install them all. Make sure you really have installed them all. Make sure  you have opened the right Python(with OpenCV installed).

Comment: I have installed them both, I still get he same error, any other suggestions?

Comment: I am using the system version of python version 2.7.1, I do not have any other installed.

Answer (score 4):

> First install `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python`:

For python2:

```
$(sudo) python2 -m pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python
```

For python3:

```
$(sudo) python3 -m pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python
```

> Then call try again. For OpenCV 3.x, use `cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` to create:

```
$ python
>>> import cv2 
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0-dev'
>>> sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
>>> sift
<xfeatures2d_SIFT 0x7f79ca721d10>
```

Comment: Do not mix both of the packages. `opencv-python` contains the main OpenCV modules. `opencv-contrib-python` contains **both** the main modules and contrib modules. The packages use the same namespace and installing one on top of another may cause issues. If you need SIFT, `pip install opencv-contrib-python` is enough.

Comment: I read `opencv-contrib-python` document again, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python, find you are right, the later contains before. I compile OpenCV by myself, do not that farmaler with it.